# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Got freezing while preparing to install

Tags: 12.04

I've downloaded Via http Ubuntu Desktop ISO and used a Usb stick as per Ubuntu instructions I've done all and got it to the installation point and 
then preparing to install when i click continue it takes forever 
It's not hanging whole computer i can still work on Firefox without any problem but Ubuntu preparing to install window freeze 
Please help on this what can i do ? Why is this freezing ?

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem myself! Luckily, I found a useful answer: No hard drive formatting, or mucking around with partitions required! Its a bit complex, and you need to use the terminal.

Open up Ubuntu like you normally would, from your flash drive.

Click "Try Ubuntu".

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

A terminal, or a cute purple box, will appear!

Leave it open for the time being and start the installer, untick all the boxes, and click"Next". Ouch! It hung.

Here comes the tricky part...
Type

```
ps -ef | egrep "dosfsck|ntfs"
```

something like this will show:

```
waterlubber@UbuntuAcer:~$ ps -ef | egrep "dosfsck|ntfs"
ubuntu    4458  4401  0 18:02 pts/0    00:00:00 egrep --color=auto dosfsck|ntfs
root      4313 4242  stuff stuff stuff ............................ntfs
```

Note the "4313" next to "root". This is important

Now, type

```
sudo kill 4313
```

Replace 4313 with whatever number is next to"root" on the list. You may find some other stuff, try to figure out which number is the Process ID. (Thats that 4313 we saw earlier)

Don't bother killing ubuntu, if you do, nothing will happen other then a not found message

Repeat the process of typing

```
ps -ef | egrep "dosfsck|ntfs"
```

and killing the process until 'ubuntu' is the lone survivor. Take a look at the installer...is it working? If not, try it again! If worst comes to worst, make sure you don't have too many partitions with 'gparted' (Its in applications)

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Download Ubuntu 13.10, it normally solves compatibility issues of that type, what I would do is to disable UEFI in BIOS and enable Legacy boot. You will now have no problems to install. Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely the problem went away for me after I did 2 thinks:

- Deleted the existing NTFS partition.
- Connected the computer to an internet connection.

Not sure if it was the combination of both or simply the internet connection.
After 2.5 wasted hours it was very dissappointing to discover that Ubuntu will hang when installed off a live USB stick if internet is not present.